# how do i prevent a nav plugin from duplicating itself in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins, menu, double

Someone please help, I'm loosing it, I have started creating a website using different themes, and i needed to add a second menu, so i did. Now, this menu has manifested as a sticky menu at the top of the page and also as a static in the header. Ive gotten it to disappear from the header on several occasions by finagling with the code, but i don't know how i did it, and it eventually keeps coming back. Can someone please assist me in removing the menu from the header, so it is just a sticky at the top of the page?

the site is http://www.dynasty-management.com

Just click on a link, it will show up. If not its still messed up, take my word for it please.

On a lighter note, in the about page and the philosophy page, how do i get the pictures to resize and fit within the lines in a mobile atmosphere.

Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

The menu you have is a premium plugin called [stripe](http://bonfirethemes.com/_stripe/) by bonfire , not a theme. In order to let it go you will need to deactivate the plugin.

It is a bit strange that you are using such a plugin which is a paid premium one without realising what it is doing ..

Comment: Yes, i know, i paid for it. The problem I'm having is that the menu is doubling up. There is one at the top of the screen that scrolls with the site, which is the one i want, and there is another within the header, which is the one i don't want. I'm pretty sure the plugin is only suppose to display one menu, unless i am going crazy... which is very possible.

Comment: The plugin is displaying the menu twice because it is defined in your theme in 2 different menu locations that are actually the same ..